# how to Select Value from drop down that is not having ID or Name

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Unable to Select the Value Test3 from the dropdown in selenium Webdriver
Here is the HTML source of the Drop down

```
> <tr><td>Case Categories</td>
<td><select class="chzn-select" multiple="multiple" style="width: 500px" data-placeholder="Select categories..." size="4" name="categories[]" id="categories">
<option value="2">Test1</option>
<option value="3">Test2</option>
<option value="4">Test3</option>
<option value="1">Test</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

below is the selenium code written to select the value

```
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.default")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.search-choice-close")).click();`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('categories')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.get_attribute("value") == "4":
        option.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code:

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("categories")));
dropDown.selectByVisibleText("Test3");
```

Or

```
dropDown.selectByValue("4");
```

Comment: This code is trying to find drop down by id and at the same creating an instance of `Select` class. By instance of `Select` you can select the different options of `select` webelement.

Comment: Have a look to see different methods of `Select` class http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use xpath to identify the element and perform the required action on it

```
String xpath="//tr/td[2]/select/option[3]";
(or) xpath="//tr/td[2]//option[3]";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
```

you can use different criteria based xpaths to find the element, you can find most of the elements on any page using xpaths